# Set Duration of Long Key press Listener

Tags: android

Can we set duration for Long key press listener? What i want is, if user keeps touching the screen for 3 sec then my long key press listener should trigger and open my pop up for setting.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: setting is your app setting or android setting tab???

Answer (score 1):

Override onTouch Listener ,then handle pressed,released event and set timer during button pressed (event == "pressed")

```
private Timer timer;

 public LongClickTimer(int seconds) {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new LongClickTask(), seconds *1000);         
        }
 class LongClickTask extends TimerTask {
            public void run() { 
             // do what you want            
                timer.cancel(); 
            }
        }
     button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.v(TAG, "EVENT" + event.toString());
                    if(event.getAction == 2) {// pressed                        
                    new LongClickTimer(5); // schedule for 5 seconds
                    }else{          
                     timer.cancel();
                    }
               return false;
              }
           });
```

Comment: Thanks Yahor10  can you send me the implemenation of your.. startTimer() and getTimer() how to implement or its full code Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for your help but its not fulfilling my problem I want If user hold touch for N seconds after that my stuff will go...Like if user touch and keep touching for 3 seconds then my function will call.... any idea ???(keep screen touch for N seconds)

Comment: you keep screen touch here  if(event.getAction == 2 && !pressed){//  }Instead button set your screen layout

Comment: I tried this code                                         if(event.getAction == 2 && !pressed) this statement is true on first touch to the button because both condition true when user touch the button. It wont work for my problem long press for 3 seconds. Hope I made my problem clear to you.If user press button for # seconds then trigger happens thanks

Comment: check my update.You was right i have some mistakes in previous code

Answer (score 1):

From Android 2.0, Activity contains the method

```
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

For exemple, a long key press on the back button would be :

```
@override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Now to open the setting tab you can do following code inside and activity...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
activityContext.startActivity(intent);
```

For detail [you can visit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for better understanding.

Comment: Need a solution for If long press is equal to 3 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Long Press Listener u can set a Handler with 3 Sec Limit and if it reaches 3 sec time then u can run your method in it or else make default method