# Duration of longClick listener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener

I want to reduce the time after which my list view respond to long Click Listener. Is it possible to reduce to long Click duration?

```
getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int position, long id) {

                    if(selectedHabit){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(),AddScheduleEventActivity.class );
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_EVENT);
                        return true;
                    }



                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you show some codes?

Comment: Everything is possible! Show us what you have tried.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473757/android-long-key-press-listener

Comment: I have a fargment that extends ListFragment. And I want to reduce the duration of onItemLongClickListener. I dont have the object of MotionEvent to calculate the click duration. Guide me please.

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the duration from on click on list items and not on individual views? Please guide me.

Comment: please accept my answer if it helped you out. thx

Answer (score 5):

You could use a OnTouchListener:

```
    private int lastTouchedViewId = -1;
    private long duration = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private long LONG_CLICK_DURATION = 1000;
```

...

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {


                switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {


                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        if (lastTouchedViewId != view.getId()) {
                            lastTouchedViewId = view.getId();
                            duration = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            if(duration-System.currentTimeMillis()> LONG_CLICK_DURATION)

                            doStuff();
                        }
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        lastTouchedViewId = -1;
                        return true;
                }


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: The view captured by the touchlistener is not the selected item but the listview. Is there a way to get the listview?