# Button starts a new activity if it is pressed for 5 seconds

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to start a new activity if the button is pressed for 5 seconds. I am using on Touch Listener.

The code i am using is as below:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {

                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

How can i use handler in between this, Thankyou

Comment: Why do you need this, just use simpleGestureDetector and start your activity on long press ( override onLongPress() method)

Answer (score 2):

You should do like this-

```
//class member
private long firstTime=0,secondTime=0;
```

now in the method

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                      firstTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                      secondTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                      if(secondTime-firstTime>=5000){ // at least 5000 ms touch down time
                          // launch your target activity from here
                      }else{ //ignore it}
                    firstTime=0; //reseting the value for the next time
                    secondTime=0;//reseting the value for the next time

                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you there. Schedule a task and then check if the button is still pressed.
[Android Touch Event determining duration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12473930/1027550)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getActionMasked();

            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                prev=System.currentTimeMillis(); 

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                    || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                curr=System.currentTimeMillis();
                if(curr-prev>=5000){
                   //do your actions here,prev,curr are fields in a class
                 }
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }`
```